# Labeling points numerically in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, arcgis-9.3

I just created a points Shapefile, with 300 points.

Using ArcGIS Desktop 9.3 I now need to label all of them numerically.

Is there a way of labelling all of them, instead of me going to the attribute table and label them manually?

Answer (score 4):

Aragon deals with the *placement* of the labels (Maplex is infinitely better if you have it), however to actually *create* the numeric labels should be quite simple:

- "Add Field" on the attributes table. Make it a type Long Integer
- Right click on this new field and go to "field calculator".
- Double click on "FID", your box should now contain: `[FID]`. When you hit "OK" the FID (which is an incremental number) will be copied over to this column and you'll have your numbers.

Note - FID starts at 0. So if you want your numbers to start at 1, you'll need to change `[FID]` to `[FID] + 1` in the last stage.

---

Actually strictly speaking that isn't even necessary now I look. If you just go to the "Labels" tab and click on **expression**, if you enter `[FID] + 1` you'll get the same result without having to create a new column.

Comment: Spot on. You can just use the FID field.  You can tweak the presentation of the labels by clicking on 'Expression' next to the label field and then add some simple VB (e.g. [FID] + 1, or "Fred_" + [FID]).  To get even fancier using just the [FID] or [OID] field you can also define classes of labels by selecting "Define classes of features and label each differently" from the first drop-down box.  You then can set up SQL queries to define sets of features to be labelled differently e.g. you could label your 300 points by having a different colour, font-dace and size for each 100 (if relevant).

Comment: I wanted to keep it simple, but @SylvesterSneekly is correct, you can concatenate arbitrary strings or other fields (though you don't need VB for these).

Answer (score 1):

you can use Maplex Label Engine for labelling points.

there are some videos here:

1.[Enable the Maplex extension](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/tutorials/maplex/Maplex_1.htm)

2.[Stack labels with Maplex](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/tutorials/maplex/Maplex_5.htm)

3.[Where you can find labelling tools](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/tutorials/maplex/Maplex_3.htm)

you can finf other videos [here](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/tutorials/maplex/maplex_tutorial_index.htm).

i hope it helps you...

Comment: Note: The Maplex Engine is only available with ArcInfo licensing levels.